# How to get this equation by using the sum of the Fourier coefficients

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $G=SU(2)$. Let $t_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta} & 0 \\  0 & e^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix}$ where $\theta\in \Bbb R$. Let $f\in C^{\infty}(G)$. Define $$F_f(\theta)=(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})\int_G f(xt_\theta x^{-1})dx$$ where $dx$ is normalized to have total mass one. My textbook says that we have the following equation $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}F_f(\theta)d\theta=\frac{d}{d\theta}F_f(\theta)\Big|_{\theta=0}$$
by using the sum of the Fourier coefficients. Could anyone expand this explanation a little bit more?
Thanks!